# How can I get objects from array with specific id compares from another array numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I need to compare id objects array from a firstArray and array numbers (secondArray) and return a new array with objects from the first array which id number exists in the second array.

So at the end, I want a new array with objects with id 39 and 41.

Actually I find something like this:

`const result = arr2.filter(o => arr1.find(x => x.id === o));`

```
const arr1 =
"blocks": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "functions": [ 0, 1 ]
    },
    {
      "id": 39,
      "functions": [ 0, 1, 3, 4 ]
    },
    {
      "id": 41,
      "functions": [ 0, 1 ]
    }
]
```

`const arr2 = [39, 41]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function during filtering. `Includes()` works like `in array` function.

```js
const arr1 =
 [ {
      "id": 1,
      "functions": [ 0, 1 ] },
    {
      "id": 39,
      "functions": [ 0, 1, 3, 4 ]
    },
    {
      "id": 41,
      "functions": [ 0, 1 ]
    }
]

const arr2 = [39, 41]
const result = arr1.filter(o => arr2.includes(o.id));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Map` to see whether there is an item of Map exists in filtering array. Getting an item from `Map` method is `O(1)`:

```js
const blocks = [
{
  "id": 1,
  "functions": [
    0,
    1
  ]
},
{
  "id": 39,
  "functions": [
    0,
    1,
    3,
    4
  ]
},
{
  "id": 41,
  "functions": [
    0,
    1
  ]
}
];

const arr2 = [39, 41];
const arr2Maps = new Map(arr2.map(a=>[a, a]));
const result = blocks.filter(o => arr2Maps.get(o.id));
console.log(result)
```

In addition, you can use `filter` and `some` methods. However, `some` method has `O(n)`:

```js
const blocks = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "functions": [
        0,
        1
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 39,
      "functions": [
        0,
        1,
        3,
        4
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 41,
      "functions": [
        0,
        1
      ]
    }
];

const arr2 = [39, 41]

const result = blocks.filter(o => arr2.some(a=> a ==o.id ));    
console.log(result)
```